# How to create lines in pygame and make it so that the character will get set to position (600, 600) when they touch it?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make it so that when the player, who is created using pygame.draw.rect, tries to move through walls1 without completing the first challenge, they are sent to coordinates (600, 600), AKA where they started from. Right now when I run the code below only the corners of walls1 do this. Thanks!

```
        walls1 = pygame.draw.lines(win, (100, 100, 100), False, [(screen_width - 100, screen_height),
                                                        (screen_width - 100, screen_height - 100),
                                                        (screen_width, screen_height - 100)], 5)
        wall_dimentions = [(screen_width - 100, screen_height),
                           (screen_width - 100, screen_height - 100),
                           (screen_width, screen_height - 100)]
        for b in range(100):
            wall_dimentions.append((screen_width - b, screen_height))
            wall_dimentions.append((screen_width, screen_height - b))
        print(wall_dimentions)
        for i in range(len(wall_dimentions)):
            if isOver(player, wall_dimentions[i]):
                player_pos_x = 600
                player_pos_y = 600
```

isOver:

```
# checks if one object is over another object in a GUI
def isOver(self, pos):
    if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
        if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured out how to make it so that the user physically can't move past the barrier (walls1), which is actually better then what I initially intended anyway.

Here's the code:

```
walls1 = pygame.draw.lines(win, (100, 100, 100), False, [(screen_width - 100, screen_height),
                                                        (screen_width - 100, screen_height - 100),
                                                        (screen_width, screen_height - 100)], 5)
        wall_dimensions = [(screen_width - 100, screen_height),
                           (screen_width - 100, screen_height - 100),
                           (screen_width, screen_height - 100)]
        for b in range(100):
            wall_dimensions.append((screen_width - 100, screen_height - b))
            wall_dimensions.append((screen_width - 100, screen_height - b))
            wall_dimensions.append((screen_width - b, screen_height - 100))
            wall_dimensions.append((screen_width - b, screen_height - 100))
        for i in range(len(wall_dimensions)):
            if isOver(player, wall_dimensions[i]):
                what_dimension = wall_dimensions[i]
                player_pos_x = what_dimension[0]
                player_pos_y = what_dimension[1]
                print(what_dimension)
```